# Microsoft Cognitive Service - Handwriting Recognition - Confidence Property

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying the handwriting recognition API on MS cognitive service, obviously, the results must be not correct in 100%, so we need the confidence value/property of each word returned by API to mark the results in different color, for example, black for high confidence and red for low confidence. User could realize which word are right and which words might be wrong. I didn't find out any information about confidence on azure service.
I need help~~~

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: Does the Cognitive Handwriting Recognition API support word confidence property?

Answer (score 0):

[I work on this OCR API at Microsoft]

Sorry for the delayed response - this is a frequently requested feature and is on our product roadmap. Unfortunately, at this time, I cannot provide a specific timeline on when it would be enabled.